# Pass javascript variable via cookie to another page and retrieve using php

Tags: php, javascript, function, cookies

I am using Google Maps API v3 to set a marker and I am having trouble submitting the marker coordinates to a MYSQL database via PHP. I am trying to pass the javascript value for "event.latlng" to the submission page via a cookie. Since PHP is loaded server-side first, I can't use PHP to pass the variable via URL to the submission page. So I am passing the static variables via PHP to the submission page. I can't get the cookie part working though. I thought that with a javascript function dedicated to retrieving the current coordinates of the marker and placing them in a cookie, I could call that function with onclick in a href button submission link. No luck so far. "mapNew4.php" is the page I have the map on, "saveLocation.php" is the submission (to the database via PHP) page. This is the important parts of the "mapNew4.php" page. I haven't tried to retrieve the cookie yet on the "saveLocation.php" page because this code already causes the "mapNew4.php" page to stop loading. Everything else works fine without the addition of the javascript function and onclick call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myLatLng()
{
var myLatLng = event.latLng;
setcookie('mapNew4['myLatLng']', time()+(10), '/');
return false;
};

</script>

<?php
<li>
<a href="saveLocation.php/?meetID='. $meetingID .'&courseID='. $courseID .'&groupID='.        $groupID .'" onclick="javascript:myLatLng();"  data-icon="check" data-transition="flip"      style="background: green;">Save</a>
</li>
?>
```

Comment: you can set and fetch cookie from both js and php, set cookie with js for example you set cookie with js named called "simple" so you can fetch it with php like this : $_COOKIE['simple'];

Answer (score 0):

Since `myLatLng()` always returns false and it is called via `onclick`, the target of the link (specified in the `href` attribute) never gets called.  There may be other problems, but certainly you mean for `saveLocation.php` to get called when the link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP code seems to be wrong either. You are declaring HTML within the PHP block. Is this site even loading? Your JS callback function uses an event variable. Where does it come from. Some browsers would use the click event of your link here when event has not been declared elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry about that, I left out the echo in the truncated version. It works fine without the javascript function.

Comment: Also the event.latlng variable is defined above in a part I left out (default part of google maps api).